# How can people be weightless on space station?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, free-body-diagram, satellites

I had read it somewhere that on the space station, people are weightless. even though artificial gravity is created there, people are still weightless. how can this be possible if there is gravity, even if it's created? to make a person weightless, shouldn't gravity be zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to an amusement park, and ride on a [*drop tower*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_tower). For just a second or two, when the car starts to drop, you will feel exactly what the astronauts in the space station feel all day and night. During that second or two, you will experience the same gravity that you experience when you are sitting in a chair on the ground, but you won't *feel* the gravity.

The reason why you won't feel the gravity is, You *never* feel gravity. When you're sitting in a chair on the ground, what you feel isn't gravity. You feel the chair *pushing up* against your butt as it prevents you from falling toward the center of the Earth. During the first second or two of the drop-tower ride, it *doesn't* push up against against your butt, and you *do* fall... until they put on the brakes and bring you to a safe stop.

Nothing "pushes up" against the astronaut's butts because they (and the whole space station) are moving in a direction that does not intersect the Earth. They literally are *falling* 24/7/365. That's what an orbit is. The space station always is falling, but it also always is moving "sideways" so fast that it always misses hitting the ground.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_cannonball

https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/

Answer (score 0):

We can also have the state of weightlessness with the presence of gravity! That is free-fall , to feel weight another force must act on you physically but during free fall we feel weightless because there's no force to stop us from falling (except air but that's negligible in this case for seeking weight).

The same thing happens in the space station , There is gravity but its in an orbit meaning its free falling constantly but has the enough horizontal speed to avert free fall and continue its orbit! Hence they feel weightlessness

Artificial gravity you are talking about is just about creating a force such that the person in the space ship experiences the same $9.8 ms^{-2}$ acceleration as in earth see:[this](https://spacemath.gsfc.nasa.gov/weekly/10Page59.pdf)